# How to get the python plotly line graph on a web page by calling the python script through HTML?

Tags: python, html, web, graph, plotly

I have written a Python code using plotly library that generates a line graph, I want to run the same python file when I run on the HTML. How to run the Python script dynamically on the web browser/web page?

**Python Script**

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
from numpy import nan as NA
import glob
from pathlib import Path
import plotly.graph_objects as go

p = Path(r'c:\Users\shivarad\Documents')  # path to files
files = list(p.rglob('*graph22.csv'))  # get files

fig = go.Figure()
for f in files: 
    file_name = f.stem  
    df = pd.read_csv(f, dtype={'Pass Percentage': int, 'original_pass_percent':int})
    df = df.sort_values(by=['build ID'], axis = 0)  
    print(df.head())  
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['build ID'], y=df['Pass Percentage'],mode='lines',name=file_name))
fig.update_layout(title='Pass Percent VS Build ID of all the Test Suites',plot_bgcolor='rgb(230, 
230,230)',showlegend=True)
fig.show()
```

I want to render the above python file in an HTML file and want to the run the python file with a button or click.

**HTML Script**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <title>OV Daily Test Results</title>
<body>
   <form action="cgi-bin/results.py" method="post">
    <input type="Submit" name="show_last_runs" value="Display Results For Last 2 Runs"></br></br>
    <b>Enter Build id</b></br>
    <input type="text" name="build_id_2_runs" size="15"><br>
    <input type="Submit" name="show_last_2_runs" value="Show Results For Last 2 Runs"></br></br>
    <input type="Submit" name="collect_last_2_runs" value="Collect Results For Last 2 Runs"></br> 
</br></br>

    <b>Enter Build id</b></br>
    <input type="text" name="build_id" size="15"><br>
    <input type="Submit" name="show_button" value="Show Results">
    <input type="submit" name="refresh_button" value="Collect Results" />
</form>

<form action="toweb.py" method="post">

<label form="Test suites">For Bar Graph Choose the Test Suite:</label>
    <input type="submit" name="Test_suites" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

How to fetch the Python plotly graph results dynamically on the web page, or suggest me anything that would work to get the results on web page.

Comment: Strategy: open a BytesIO stream, call the fig.write_html method on that stream, decode that stream to a string, send string to client (via building the html directly or Ajax).

Comment: Also, Tell us a bit more how you plan to call a Python script from a browser. To me that seems strange at best.

Comment: I am new to  Ajax,  Actually I tried to call this python script with help of CGI,  but no luck I am not able to view the results on the web page. So Please guide me whichever the possible way that i can get the line graph dynamically on the web page

Comment: Well, that is a larger question than appropriate for Stackoverflow. Probably the easiest way would be to serve your website from a Python Flask server. Upon a get request, you create the plot, convert it to a html string as I described above, insert it into a Jinja template and send it off to the client. https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/ There are sufficient tutorials on all of these problems online to get you started. No CGI needed this way. If for some reasons you need to use an existing webserver just let it forward any get requests for the plot to the Flask server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dash.
from the dash [website](https://dash.plotly.com/introduction):

> Through a couple of simple patterns, Dash abstracts away all of the technologies and protocols that are required to build an interactive web-based application. Dash is simple enough that you can bind a user interface around your Python code in an afternoon.

The code will be something like this:

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
app = dash.Dash(__name__)
# here you should build your fig, don't use fig.show()
app.layout = html.Div([dcc.Graph(id='fig', figure=fig)])
app.run_server()
```